# How to change value of arguments in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, global-variables

I want to pass n variables to a function in python and have the function sanitize these variables. My first attempt at this was

```
list_of_variables = [a, b, c,]
def sanitize(*args):
    for arg in args:
        arg = str(arg) #example
sanitize(*list_of_variables)
```

but arg becomes a local variable and the original array remains unaffected.

Attempt#2

```
for arg in args:
    global arg
```

but this didnt work since arg is assigned before global declaration. putting global arg above the loop also didnt work.

is there a way to make this function perform a certain action over n variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you put your var(s) in a list, there is no need to use indirection, just read the list in sanitize :

```
a=10
b= 12/3
c= "ABCDEF"

list_of_variables = [a, b, c]

def sanitize(aList):
    for i in range (0, len(aList)):
        aList[i] = str(aList[i])

sanitize(list_of_variables)
print(list_of_variables)
```

result : `['10', '4.0', 'ABCDEF']`

But this will not work with `sanitize(a,b,c)` as python creates a tuple, not a list and a tuple cannot be modified;

if you want to use sanitize with a free list of var(s), you must return something else than the initial tuple. A code could be :

```
def sanitize(*args):
    aList=[]
    for arg in args:
        aList.append(str(arg))
    return aList

result = sanitize(a,b,c)
print(result)
```

You get : `['10', '4.0', 'ABCDEF']`

But take care that in any case of these examples, a, b or c stay unchanged.
`print (a,b,c)` will always give `10 4.0 ABCDEF`

You are not manipulating pointers as it could be in C !

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You can reassign members of a list like this:

```py
def sanitize(args):
    for index,arg in enumerate(args):
        args[index] = str(arg) #example

list_of_variables = [a, b, c,]
sanitize(list_of_variables)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return the sanitised variables back from the function to the caller. Besides, since you're passing the list to the function when you call it, you don't need the non-keyword variables `*kwargs`, since lists are perfectly good variables that can serve as arguments for a function:

```
list_of_variables = [a, b, c]
def sanitize(*args):
    l = []
    for arg in args:
        l.append(str(arg)) 
    return l

list_of_variables = sanitize(list_of_variables)
```